# On FC 18 machine mq_open fails with error no EMFILE

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I am trying to open a new message queue, but it fails with too many open files (24) error.

Here is my sample code:

```
#define ALERT_Q_NAME "/alert_q_test"

mqd_t mqdes;

int main()
{
    struct mq_attr attr;

    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 512;
    attr.mq_msgsize = 1536;

    mqdes = mq_open(ALERT_Q_NAME, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0600, &attr);
    if(mqdes == (mqd_t) -1)
    {
            printf("Failed:%d(%s)\n",errno,strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Passed\n");
            mq_close(mqdes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The system wide limit for number of message queues that can be created is:

> $cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/queues_max
>   
>   256

I am sure this system limit isn't reached since I am running this sample code on a newly installed FC18 box. Neways just to confirm it, I mounted the message queue filesystem:

> $mkdir /dev/mqueue 
>   $mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue 
>   $ ls -l /dev/mqueue 
>   total 0 
>   $gcc -g -o mqueue mqueue.c -lrt 
>   $./mqueue 
>   Failed:24(Too many open files) 
>   $ ls -l /dev/mqueue 
>   total 0

Jus like FC18, I am unable to create message queues on Linux boxes running on kernel version 3.6.10 and 3.6.11. While the same program runs fine on Linux 2.6.31 and Linux 3.3.4. 
 
Seems like it got broke down somewhere. Or what am I missing here? Any help please?!? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

A little late answer, but:

mq_open can fail with errno=EMFILE if too many files are open or if the max mqueue size was overstepped.

See RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE in [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)  for more information on the size calculation.

To get the current soft/hard limits:

```
grep -E 'Limit|queue' /proc/self/limits
```

To change limits permanently, edit /etc/security/limits.conf and login user again with 'su - '.

/etc/security/limits.conf:

```
[user] hard msgqueue unlimited
[user] soft msgqueue unlimited
```

Another possibility is to set softlimit with setrlimt(2)/prlimit(2).
If hardlimit is to small for your purposes, CAP_SYS_RESOURCE is needed.

Answer (score 2):

One probelem I've seen is that, even if we set attr to NULL, the default values are too large for the per-process limits @wr0112358 discusses above.

So we can be well under the whole system limits found in

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
128
# cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max
65536
```

while exceeding our per-process ulimits.

```
# ulimit -a |grep queue
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
```

One quick solution you can use to check is to increase the ulimit:

```
# ulimit -q unlimited
```

or set the rlimit as noted by @wr0112358 for a more permanent solution.